# Modificar Iframe de youtube

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, youtube

tengo la siguiente pregunta ¿como modificar elementos(a nivel de CSS o por JS) dentro de un iframe de youtube?

Comment: ¿Por qué querrías modificar los elementos de un iframe de youtube en vez de poner tus propios elementos encima?

Comment: Es que es una lista de reproducción, y quiero que la barra lateral donde aparecen todos los vídeos, siempre este visible

Comment: Puedes agregar un ejemplo de como estás cargando el iframe? Según yo era una de tantas opciones configurables.